# Proof that the Laplacian of Poisson's fundamental solution is zero everywhere except at the origin?

Tags: distribution-theory, laplacian, greens-function, fundamental-solution

I know that these things are better calculated using spherical coordinates and/or Fourier transforms. I tried to calculate this in cartesian coordinates anyway:

Let $G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x_0}) = \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}|}$ be the fundamental solution for the Laplace operator $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n= 3$.

This means that $\Delta_{\mathbf{x}} G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x_0}) = \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0})$, which should be $0$ everywhere except at $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x_0}$ (where it must be treated as a distribution instead of a normal function).

Let $\mathbf{x_0} = 0$ for simplicity, then:

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta G(\mathbf{x}) & = \nabla^2 \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|} \\
& = \nabla \left(-\frac{1}{\mathbf{|x|}^3}\mathbf{x}\right) \\
& = \frac{2}{|\mathbf{x}|^3}
\end{align}
$$

This is a strictly positive function everywhere except at $\mathbf{x}=0$, so it clearly is not equal to $0$ (even in the sense of distributions).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See Example 15 on page 102 in the part Theory of distributions in the book Green's functions and boundary values problems by Ivar Stakgold and Michael Holst. The distribution laplacian is calculated  rigorously there.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen proofs that use spherical coordinates, Fourier transforms or other tools. However, I would still like to know why my calculation does not yield $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is wrong.
$$\Delta G(x)=\nabla\cdot \nabla G(x)=\nabla\cdot \nabla \frac{1}{|x|}$$
$$=\nabla\cdot \left(-\frac{\vec{x}}{|x|^3}\right)$$
And the divergence of $-\frac{\vec{x}}{|x|^3}$ is equal to $0$. You just have to compute it carefully:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(-\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\right)=-\frac{(x_i)'\cdot |x|^3-x_i\cdot (|x|^3)'}{|x|^6}=-\frac{|x|^3-3x_i|x|^2\left(\frac{1}{2|x|}\right)2x_i}{|x|^6}$$
$$=-\frac{|x|^3-3x_i^2|x|}{|x|^6}$$ Then the divergence is 
$$\nabla\cdot\left(-\frac{\vec{x}}{|x|^3}\right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(-\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\right)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}{-\frac{|x|^3-3x_i^2|x|}{|x|^6}}=0$$

**Note** that this is true only for $n=3$.